# How to plot different column of a Pandas data frame with different marker, using pandas.plot() function?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a pandas data frame with 5 different column. 
I want to plot them with different color, lable, and marker for each column.
I manage to make a different color and different label for each column, by passing a list of colors/label for each column. However this does not work for the marker. Any idea on how to do it?
Here is the code example:

```py
ds # a pandas data frame with 3 columns

list_label=['A','B','C']
list_color=['tab:red','tab:green','tab:blue']
list_marker=['o','s','v']

ds.plot(color=list_color, label=list_label, marker=list_marker)
```

The later line produce an error  like `AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'list_marker'`

Answer (score 3):

Plot each Series separately on the same figure so you can specify the correct marker.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (10, 3)))
list_label=['A', 'B', 'C']
list_color=['tab:red', 'tab:green', 'tab:blue']
list_marker=['o', 's', 'v']
```

---

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, col in enumerate(df):
    df[col].plot(color=list_color[i], marker=list_marker[i], label=list_label[i], ax=ax)

plt.legend()    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea! But I was wondering if there was a solution without using a loop, as it can be done for the color or the label keyword.